# Multi-Context InMemory Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to have an InMemory database (ASP.NET Core) that is shared across multiple DbContexts? It seems that each DbContext type keeps its own database, even when the same database name is specified in UseInMemoryDatabase.

Comment: Same name should be enough.

Comment: Same name is NOT enough if the ServicesProvider are not the same. (It is specified in the documentation)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible nowadays, but indeed passing just the name is not enough if you use different context types. I'm using .net core 2.2 and had the exact same issue. My code now is now like this:

I create a InMemoryDatabaseRoot object like this in class level

```
//using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
private static readonly InMemoryDatabaseRoot InMemoryDatabaseRoot = new InMemoryDatabaseRoot();
```

When I add the db contextes I pass the root instance

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyContext", InMemoryDatabaseRoot);
    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
 });

 services.AddDbContext<MySecondContext>(options =>
 {
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyContext", InMemoryDatabaseRoot);
    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
  });
```

I found it in a discussion here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9613#issuecomment-430722420

Comment: Verified on DNCore 3.1 as well.  Full namespace/object and unambiguous member variable name for future readers : private static readonly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.InMemoryDatabaseRoot InMemoryDatabaseRootInstance = new InMemoryDatabaseRoot();

Comment: But thank you.  I've moved to a CQSR pattern (separate the Commands (Create/Update/Delete in CRUD) from the Query(ies) (Read of the CRUD) in one project, and this was the only place my unit tests were failing...because I have a regular Context, and a readonly Context.  I needed the regular Context and readonly Context to share the same InMemoryDatabase.

Comment: Should this solution still be working in dotnet/efcore 6 times? Any ideas what I might be doing incorrectly [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9613#issuecomment-1218165126)?

Comment: My issue seems to be that I was using 2x different sets of entity models between the 2x DbContexts. Maybe the In-Memory store cannot be shared between 2x DbContexts unless the identity models that the contexts use are shared? [More info](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28778#issuecomment-1221324545)

Answer (score 4):

The same name is enough. If your instances of DbContext do not 'see' the same in memory DB, it seems they use ones with different names. Make sure your DbContext is created once for the same name.

`EF Core 2.0` even re-uses in memory databases with the same name:

> **In-memory databases must be named**
>
> The global unnamed in-memory database has been removed and instead all in-memory databases must be named. For example:

```
optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDatabase");
```

> This creates/uses a
>   database with the name “MyDatabase”. **If `UseInMemoryDatabase` is called again with the same name, then the same in-memory database will be used**, allowing it to be shared by multiple context instances.

Comment: I am finding this is a problem when using the same name with an inherited DBContext and its base class, they have different data. this will be due to @Jens answer that the model must be the same

Answer (score 4):

Beside the same database name, the model must also be the same.
This means that in case of an own implementation of IModelCacheKeyFactory, it's Create-Method must return "equal" objects.