# Multiple in-memory databases with the same name

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

In relation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446491/596758), I'm trying to get multiple context to work by setting `UseInMemoryDatabase` to the same name. The test below fails, and the secondContext is empty.

**What else do I need to do to share the same in memory database?**

```
[Test]
public void MultipleContextTest()
{
    var firstContext = new FirstContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FirstContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("DB").Options);
    firstContext.Add(new Entity() {Name = "Test"});
    firstContext.SaveChanges();

    var secondContext = new SecondContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SecondContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("DB").Options);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, secondContext.Entity.Count());
}

public class FirstContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entity { get; set; }

    public FirstContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}

public class SecondContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entity { get; set; }

    public SecondContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}

public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are there two different context *types* if they're exposing the same entity types? It looks like the only sharing anticipated is when the context type matches.

Comment: I do think it's a valid question. There are "some" scenario's where you have 2 different contexes targetting the same DB.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever To spare SO from all production code and abstractions, I created an easy to follow example that anyone could copy/paste and run.

Comment: One practical example...(for me) is 2 DbContexts.  But one is a "ReadOnly" DbContext that uses a custom Interceptor (DbCommandInterceptor / IDbCommandInterceptor : IInterceptor) that does IsolationLevel.Snapshot.  I use the "ReadOnly" DbContext for "reports".  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors. as a security best practice, the connection string using at the IoC registration . uses a readonly-permission db-access-account.

Answer (score 7):

I got it working by setting the InMemoryDatabaseRoot to the same object on all contexts.

```
private InMemoryDatabaseRoot _root;
private InMemoryDatabaseRoot Root
{
    get
    {
        if(_root == null)
            _root = new InMemoryDatabaseRoot();

        return _root;
    }
}

[Test]
public void MultipleContextTest()
{
    var firstContext = new FirstContext(CreateOptions<FirstContext>());
    firstContext.Add(new Entity() {Name = "Test"});
    firstContext.SaveChanges();

    var secondContext = new SecondContext(CreateOptions<SecondContext>());


    Assert.AreEqual(firstContext.Entity.Count(), secondContext.Entity.Count());
}

private DbContextOptions CreateOptions<T>() where T : DbContext
{
    return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("DB", Root)
        .Options;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I actually found documentation for your answer : "Acts as a root for all in-memory databases such that they will be available across context instances and service providers as long as the same instance of this type is passed "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.inmemorydatabaseroot?view=efcore-7.0   emphasis on "same instance" (2 little words!!). thanks for the answer.