# How to create separate in memory database for each test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, xunit

I'm writing a test with xunit on .NET Core 3.0 and I have a problem with the in-memory database. I need a separate database for each test but now I create a single database that causes problems, but I have no idea how to create a new database for each test.

```
public class AccountAdminTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AccountAdminTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44444")
        });

        scopeFactory = _factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
}

public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                    typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));

            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(descriptor);
            }

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((options, context) =>
            {
                context.UseInMemoryDatabase("IdentityDatabase");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

---

Now it's look like this but still dosen't work. When i change lifetime on AddDbContext it doesn't change anything.

```
public class AccountAdminTest : IDisposable
{
    public AccountAdminTest(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;

        _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>();

        _client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44444")
        });

        scopeFactory = _factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        _scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();


        var _user = User.getAppAdmin();
        _context.Add(_user);
        _context.SaveChanges(); //Here i got error on secound test. It says "An item with the same key has already been added"
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
        _factory.Dispose();
        _context.Dispose();
        _client.Dispose();
    }
```

---

I can't get token when use Guid as db name. It says that username/password is not valid. I use IdentityServer for authentication

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string userName, string password, string clientId, string scope)
        {
            var disco = await _client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44444");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(disco.Error))
            {
                throw new Exception(disco.Error);
            }
            var response = await _client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = clientId,
                Scope = scope,
                UserName = userName,
                Password = password,
            });
            return response.AccessToken;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to change is this code here:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((options, context) =>
{
    context.UseInMemoryDatabase("IdentityDatabase");
});
```

Instead of the constant value `"IdentityDatabase"`, use something like `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`:

```
context.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Then, every time the context is fetched, it will be using a new in-memory database.

Comment: This does not work for me using Hotchocolate's `IRequestExecutor`. I do not know why. It seems like after executing a Request the DB is empty.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** You must specify an unique name for every test run to avoid sharing the same InMemory database as [slightly mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests) and [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264857/4943817) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446491/4943817).

Nonetheless the suggestion below to switch to "Constructor and Dispose" still applies.

---

`IClassFixture` is not the right tool to use, [the documentation says](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#class-fixture):

> When to use: when you want to create a single test context and **share it among all the tests in the class**, and have it cleaned up after all the tests in the class have finished.

In your case you have to use "[Constructor and Dispose](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#constructor)", the documentation says:

> When to use: when you want a clean test context for every test (sharing the setup and cleanup code, **without sharing the object instance**).

So your test will be:

```cs
public class AccountAdminTest
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AccountAdminTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        //
        _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>();

        _client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44444")
        });

        scopeFactory = _factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        _scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }

    //Tests...

    public void Dispose() {

        _scope.Dispose();
        _factory.Dispose();

        //Dispose and cleanup anything else...
    }

}
```

Alternatively you can specify a lifetime of `ServiceLifetime.Transient` for your `DbContext` [using this overload of `.AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_)

Comment: It didn't help. I still have the same problem.

Comment: What have you tried exactly ? Can you provide more information about your problem ? Keep in mind that InMemoryDatabase [does not function like a relational database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#inmemory-is-not-a-relational-database)

Comment: I tried "Constructor and Dispose" and changed lifetime and it didn't change anything. I run tests and first one pass but in the next one i have records in database from the previous test.

Comment: Ofcours, i did it.

Comment: What happens if you use a different database name for each test like: `context.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());` ?

Comment: Yes, and then i have diffrent db every test but I can't get token. It says that username/password is not valid, i don't know why it happens. I add code how to get token higher.

Comment: I think that deserves a question on its own. It could be that your `_client` is using a different database with a different name _but_ if that client connects to a service hosted in a separate project maybe you should think to either mock it or setup an integration test with a real database.