# Create a separate (in memory) database for each test

Tags: typescript, sqlite, jestjs, typeorm

It is possible to create a in memory database for each test?

I currently use the following code, which works if I only run one test file or use the `--run-in-band` option.

```js
import _useDb from "@/useDb";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import { createConnection, getConnection } from "typeorm";

const useDb = mocked(_useDb);

jest.mock("@/useDb");

beforeEach(async () => {
  useDb.mockImplementation(async (action) => {
    const db = await createConnection({
      type: "sqlite",
      database: ":memory:",
      dropSchema: true,
      entities: [Entity],
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
    });

    await action(db);
  });
});

afterEach(async () => {
  const con = getConnection();

  await con.close();
});
```

But as soon as I run multiple tests at the same time I get:

```
CannotExecuteNotConnectedError: Cannot execute operation on "default" connection because connection is not yet established.
```

I think I could provide a name attribute with a random uuid, like they suggested in [How to create separate in memory database for each test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641729/how-to-create-separate-in-memory-database-for-each-test) But is this really the way to go? Isn't there some kind of parameter that tells TypeORM "please don't create connections indexed by name" (or whatever it is doing)?

Comment: Check your tests and what you do as well. I had a similar problem using a different library (mock-fs) and since I loaded it early in the beforeEach, instead of it being the last thing in the beforeEach, I was getting some random errors as well with access data from it.

Comment: @StevenScott Okay, definitely something to keep in mind those bugs are always the worst, but as I said, it **only** happens when I run the tests via worker pool. So multiple default connections somehow get into the TypeORM pool.

Comment: @StevenScott so I think you were kinda right. No idea how I got it to work, but it works now. Thank you :D

Comment: Glad I pointed you in the right direction?  I know with the Mock-FS, once I did that, anything trying to access the OS failed, so that was my gotcha, even though it was the testing code, that I thought would have been already compiled and running, before the mock.  I think it might have something to do with Jest's parallel execution as well, but not 100% sure, as I did not try it with the run in sequence mode to verify this.  It might be your afterAll() gets called in a different test, and maybe messes with the mock in these tests? Not sure, but glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got it to work, now sure how, but maybe this helps someone in the future. This is my `beforeEach` and `afterEach`:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const con = await createConnection({
    type: "sqlite",
    database: ":memory:",
    dropSchema: true,
    entities: [],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
  });

  mockGetDbConnection.mockResolvedValue(con);
});

afterEach(async () => {
  const con = getConnection();

  await con.close();
});
```

`mockGetDbConnection` is the function where services get the DB handle. If you don't have that you most likely just want to use `getConnection` provided by TypeORM.

I also have this in jest `setupFilesAfterEnv` and it seems to work like a charm.