# Multiple DB contexts to a single database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am using EF in memory database to do some unit testing. I have figured out how to populate the database with some test data and to query results through the context. The problem is that I have two db contexts. One used for adding data to the table and another with views used to access data. I don't know how to create the two contexts so that they use the same database. My unit test is returning failed, because it expected 1 result but found 0.

Any suggestions?

```
[Fact]
public void WhenCallingA_ThenCallReturnThis()
{
    var tableOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TableContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDatabase")
        .Options;

    var viewOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ViewContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDatabase")
        .Options;

    using (var tableContext = new TableContext(tableOptions))
    {
        tableContext.MyTable.Add(GenerateRecord());
        tableContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var viewContext = new ViewContext(viewOptions))
    {
        Assert.Equal("HelloWorld", viewContext.MyTopics.Find(12).name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use view's when using InMemory database. We do not have the ability to create view when using InMemory database. View's is just a result of SQL statement. View's are very specific to Database. Entity framework treats the view as just another entity.

So, when you are using InMemory database. The `MyTopics` view entity and `MyTable` entity are represented as two separate tables in the memory. Populating data into `MyTable` does not fetch any results when querying `MyTopics`.

Instead you could refactor your test this way:

```
[Fact]
public void WhenCallingA_ThenCallReturnThis()
{
    var tableOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TableContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDatabase")
        .Options;

    using (var tableContext = new TableContext(tableOptions))
    {
        tableContext.MyTable.Add(GenerateRecord());
        tableContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var tableContext = new TableContext(tableOptions))
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, tableContext.MyTable.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: The contexts are different and adds different options.
TableContext adds options to write to the database and reading raw column values and ViewContext adds options to extract columns and json fields through a view.

Comment: Is the model same for both the DB Context?

Comment: Model? Both contexts works on the same table. One directly - one through views.

Comment: I think using the database name for both the context is not enough. You need to have a common service provider and InMemoryDatabaseRoot. Check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57602635/14141234).

Comment: The answer you links to suggests that the name should be enough. But also that the service provider should be the same. I tried adding the same service provider to both context options without any change.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use views when using InMemory database. Please see my response above.

Comment: Please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Hi @7heViking - I have already updated my answer above.

Comment: I give you a point for the answer but I cannot use your example. For this very simple sample I gave you, it is possible with your workaround. But as soon as the code under test starts parsing arguments like id, it cannot be done like that anymore, as the views are doing some important filtering and aggregations in their select calls.